# Manage multiple windows in App Titanium

Tags: windows, stack, titanium

At the moment,my app have many window with correspond ID..Each I want to go to other page,I create a window and add view corresspond and open it.
I want to manage windows by stack array.
Each create a new window and open it, I will push ID of that window to stack windows.Then operate test in stack array..If that ID existed,I will close window in front of with that ID.
The code is follow:

```
var stackWindows=[];  //global variable

//function test the exist of window
function testWindowExist(windows)
{

 for(var i=0;i<windows.length;i++)
 {
   for(var j=i+1;j<windows.length;j++)
    {
      if(windows[i]==windows[j])
      {
       return windows[i];  
       //close windows with ID=windows[i];
      }
      else
      {
        //do nothing
        return 0;
      }
    }
 }
```

}

I think I can get ID of windows existed but I don't know the way to close that window.
Can you help me.(Sorry,I am not good at English)

Answer (score 0):

Closing a window is really easy:

```
windows[i].close();
```

But you've got bigger issues than that, I believe. Your algorithm above is identical to this one:

```
if (windows.length < 2) return undefined;
if (windows[0] == windows[1] return windows[0];
return 0;
```

Comment: Here, windows[i] is only ID of windows,isn't a window; Can't use method close for it

Comment: Then track a stack of the windows, too.